# Resizeable boxes with constrain

Tags: jquery-ui

I have multiple boxes in a row and I have added option to resize these boxes using jQuery UI.

You can find the code on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/ZbTem/

When I resize one box it is pushing the next one to create space. How can I restrict the boxes to push the next box out from the parent?

My jQuery Code:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".resizeable" ).resizable({
        containment: "parent",
        handles: "e, w",
    });

    $( ".resizeable" ).resizable( "option", "alsoResize", $(this).siblings().not(this) ); 
});
```